# C# Linq: Split up getting results

Tags: c#, sql, linq, exception, out-of-memory

I'm currently trying to write a query to get all corresponding items from my SQL database. This is partially working however I get a OutOfMemoryException when I try to get everything (couple million of records) which isn't suprising. But I would want to know if there is a solution to this?

The more complex my query gets the less records it can pull without throwing the out of memory exception. And it should even get more complex than this because not everything is added yet.

If I even add one of the commented lines of code I can't pull the results. Adding all of them means I can only pull like around 500.000 lines of records without the memory exception.

So does anyone have any idea on how to maybe split the results up while maintaining the possibility to filter & sort?

Greetz!

```
private EventsEntities eventsEntities = new EventsEntities();

private void GetFouten()
{

    fouten = eventsEntities.Foutens;

    alleOmschrijvingen = textboxFilterOmschrijving.Text.Split(',').ToList();
    alleFouten = textboxFilterFout.Text.Split(',').ToList();
    alleModules = textboxFilterModule.Text.Split(',').ToList();
    alleNummers = textboxFilterType.Text.Split(',').ToList();



    IQueryable<ModelFouten> FoutenResultaat = (

            from x in treinen
            join fout in fouten
            on x.TreinId equals fout.TreinId

            where dateStart <= fout.Datum && dateEnd >= fout.Datum


            //&& alleTreinenIds.Contains(fout.Treinen.Name)
            //&& fout.Omschrijving.Contains(textboxFilterOmschrijving.Text)
            //&& fout.FoutCode.Contains(textboxFilterFout.Text)
            //&& fout.Module.Contains(textboxFilterModule.Text)

            //orderby fout.Datum descending, fout.Time descending

            select new ModelFouten()
            {
                Datum = fout.Datum,
                Time = fout.Time,
                FoutCode = fout.FoutCode,
                Omschrijving = fout.Omschrijving,
                Module = fout.Module.ToUpper(),
                Name = x.Name,
                FoutId = fout.FoutId,
            });


    foutensDataGrid.ItemsSource = FoutenResultaat;

}
```

Comment: Use the Take method and set up paging.

Comment: Yes, @JohnPeters is right. You should use Skip and get methods and implemet paging. For example: int itemPerPage = 10; int currentPage = 7; var result = FoutenResultaat.Skip((currentPage - 1) * itemPerPage).Take(itemPerPage).ToList(); But remember that you have to order query to be able to use Skip method

Comment: But Its important I have all the results together, because they need to be exported to Excel to draw graphs with them. I don't really care if it takes a while, as long as the results show up. with paging this isn't right?

Comment: @Goostrabha : paging will just help you retrieving your results 'step by step'. In your case, it is your job to process what you get and export (in a a same excel file) your data, package by package of your custome object fouteenResultat